# Query a table that has more than 655 columns

Tags: odbc, scada, openaccess

I tried to use database connection (ODBC) in vs 2019 and query tables in OpenAccess realtime scada database. It gaved me error as "The results viewer cannot execute a query with mroe than 655 columns...".
Anyone know

- this could be configable in vs 2019?
- you may have a tool that could handle more than 655 colums?
- open source project that I could use?
  Thanks lots!
  Shenyi